# Spark -scala create DataFrame from json file and drop basic and nested elements

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I have json file that contains json objects, each object by line.
I have the folowing schema for these objects :

```
root
   |-- endtime: long (nullable = true)
   |-- result: array (nullable = true)
   |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
   |    |    |-- hop: long (nullable = true)
   |    |    |-- result: array (nullable = true)
   |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
   |    |    |    |    |-- from: string (nullable = true)
   |    |    |    |    |-- rtt: double (nullable = true)
   |    |    |    |    |-- size: long (nullable = true)
   |    |    |    |    |-- ttl: long (nullable = true)
   |    |    |    |    |-- x: string (nullable = true)
```

The question : How I can create a new DataFrame from Dataframe containing the data in the json file given as input and deleting data as ttl and x?

```
   |    |    |    |    |-- ttl: long (nullable = true)
   |    |    |    |    |-- x: string (nullable = true)
```

Given that I am new in Spark (Scala), I don't know what are the possile ways!

It was simple to delete endtime by :

```
val pathToTraceroutesExamples = getClass.getResource("/test/sample_1.json")
val df = spark.read.json(pathToTraceroutesExamples.getPath)

// Displays the content of the DataFrame to stdout
df.show()
df.printSchema()

var newDf = df.drop("endtime")
```

Answer (score 1):

`explode` and `drop` will do the trick.  First, `explode` the first level result and then `explode` the second level result from the resulting dataframe. Finally `drop` the columns.

For instance,

```
val newDF = df
  .select(df(“*”), explode(df(“result”)).alias(“result_exp”))
  .drop(“ttl”).drop(“x”)
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea of @Kris is True; explode and then drop. I found an example [here](https://hadoopist.wordpress.com/2016/05/16/how-to-handle-nested-dataarray-of-structures-or-multiple-explodes-in-sparkscala-and-pyspark/).

I changed the attribute name result because I have another result name to avoid the confusion at the explode :

Step 1: (Input)

```
 |-- timestamp: long (nullable = true)
 |-- hopDetails: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- hop: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- result: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- from: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- rtt: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- size: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- ttl: long (nullable = true)
```

Step 2: 
Code:

```
    var exploded_1 = renamed_newDF
             .withColumn("hop", explode(renamed_newDF("hopDetails.hop")))
             .withColumn("result", explode(renamed_newDF("hopDetails.result")))
             .drop("hopDetails")
    exploded_1.printSchema
```

Output schema :

```
 |-- timestamp: long (nullable = true)
 |-- hop: long (nullable = true)
 |-- result: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- from: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- rtt: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- size: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ttl: long (nullable = true)
```

Step 3 :

Code :

```
var exploded_2 = exploded_1
  .withColumn("from", explode(exploded_1("result.from")))
  .withColumn("rtt", explode(exploded_1("result.rtt")))
  .withColumn("size", explode(exploded_1("result.size")))
  .withColumn("ttl", explode(exploded_1("result.ttl")))
  .drop("result")

exploded_2.printSchema
```

Schema :

```
    root
   |-- af: long (nullable = true)
   |-- dst_addr: string (nullable = true)
   |-- from: string (nullable = true)
   |-- msm_id: long (nullable = true)
   |-- prb_id: long (nullable = true)
   |-- src_addr: string (nullable = true)
   |-- timestamp: long (nullable = true)
   |-- hop: long (nullable = true)
   |-- rtt: double (nullable = true)
   |-- size: long (nullable = true)
   |-- ttl: long (nullable = true)
```